# JavaMail/Exchange AuthAs header for distrubtion groups

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I have a Java program which sends a regular email via our organization's Exchange server. The server with the program and the exchange server are on the same network. The email is sent to several individual email addresses, and a few distribution groups. All recipients are internal to our organization's domain. This has worked fine for the past two years.

Recently I upgraded the project's dependencies to use a more recent version of JavaMail. After this change, I've found that the email is successfully reaching individual email recipients, but members of the distribution groups are not getting the email. After comparing the old emails to the new emails, there is only one difference. This header:

```
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Authas: ⁨Internal⁩
```

has changed to:

```
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Authas: ⁨Anonymous⁩
```

I don't totally understand what this header means, but I believe this is probably why the distribution groups are not receiving the email, since they are set receive only internal emails. After noticing this problem, I reverted my changes to the JavaMail library version, but the problem persists. FWIW, the JavaMail debug output verifies the distribution group addresses as "OK".

So how can I get the Exchange server to recognize that this is an internal email?

Below is the code that sends the email, with sensitive info removed. Again, this code was working for a few years before I attempted to update the libraries. I should also mention that the distribution groups themselves seem fine, they have been receiving other email like normal.

```
            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            // Setup mail server
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "XXXXXXXX");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "30000");
            props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "30000");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication("XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
                        }
                    });

            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set the from address
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXX"));

            // Set the to address
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String formDate = formatter.format(date);
            // Set the subject
            message.setSubject("Incident Report Dispositions: " + formDate);

            // Set the content
            message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
```

EDIT: I also notice that the "anonymous" email is missing this header:

```
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Authmechanism: ⁨00⁩
```

Comment: This is probably due to a change in the way JavaMail is authenticating to your server.  Compare the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) for the two versions.  Old versions didn't support NTLM authentication but new versions do.  Also, [some versions of Exchange incorrectly report that they support PLAIN authentication](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Exchange), but in fact do not, which can cause problems for JavaMail.

Comment: @BillShannon The problem is that now I'm getting the same issue no matter which version of JavaMail I use. Which kind of authentication should I be using to get Exchange to treat the email as internal?

Comment: Sounds like something changed on the server.  You probably want NTLM authentication, but if the server changed, who knows?